# HTTP 500 Laravel 5 app using dokku on digital ocean

Tags: laravel-5, digital-ocean, dokku

So i followed the tutorial about deploying a larval 5 application using dokku and it worked but i have a HTTP ERROR 500 
can't see any logs using dukku logs
so i used

```
dokku run app /bin/bash
```

started another local server in the app directory and curl it to see in storage/logs

> No supported encrypter found. The cipher and / or key length are invalid.

which mean the APP_KEY is incorrect (i have it in .ENV in my local env) but when i push to my VPS it remove the whole line

using 
`dokku run wizzserv php artisan key:generate`
result in

```
Application key [xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx] set successfully.
```

but it's not working

TL;DR

pushed my code which work locally to Digital Ocean using dokku
deployement succeed but getting HTTP 500 
error about APP_KEY random string 
dokku remove it from .ENV

Answer (score 1):

i corrected it by just add

```
dokku config:set MyApp APP_KEY=XXXXXXX
```

where i generated the xxxxxxx using `dokku run AppName php artisan key:generate`

now it's working